# "Partitioned" sorting in a SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

The following SQL query that displays products sold sorted by cost and number of orders have to be sorted in a partitioned manner. Namely, products with the cost of under $100 should go first and then everything else that is > $100 should follow it. Adding `HAVING TS.TotalSold < 100` to the query would accomplish this for the first partition, but would filter out other products. The operation should be atomic, so that this query can be executed only once.

NOTE: cost by which the query has to be partitioned is calculated as a max of two cost columns, which makes things a bit more complicated (the proposed solutions of CASE WHEN won't work as HighestCost is not a column)

```
SELECT PS.ProductName, TS.TotalSold, 
  ((PS.Cost1 + PS.Cost2 + ABS(PS.Cost1-PS.Cost2)) / 2) as HighestCost
FROM Products as PS
   CROSS APPLY 
      (SELECT 
         (SELECT COUNT(OrderId) 
          FROM Orders as OS 
          WHERE OS.ProductId=PS.ProductId) 
       as TotalSold) TS
ORDER BY HighestCost ASC, TS.TotalSold
```

**EDIT**: modified the query to include calculated cost by which the query has to be partitioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDITED

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT PS.ProductName, TS.TotalSold, 
  ((PS.Cost1 + PS.Cost2 + ABS(PS.Cost1-PS.Cost2)) / 2) as HighestCost
FROM Products as PS
   CROSS APPLY 
      (SELECT COUNT(OrderId) as TotalSold
       FROM Orders as OS 
       WHERE OS.ProductId=PS.ProductId) TS
) SQ
ORDER BY CASE WHEN HighestCost > 100 THEN 1 END ASC, TotalSold
```

**original below**

```
SELECT PS.ProductName, TS.TotalSold
FROM Products as PS
   CROSS APPLY 
      (SELECT COUNT(OrderId) as TotalSold
       FROM Orders as OS 
       WHERE OS.ProductId=PS.ProductId) TS
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN TS.TotalSold > 100 THEN 1 END, PS.Cost ASC, TS.TotalSold
```

You may notice I removed a subquery level since it was extraneous.

Comment: thanks for a good pointer! tried it out, unfortunately it doesnt work as the query has to be partitioned not by a real column, but by a max of two columns

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which dbms you are using but in mine I would use a calculated column to assign a partitionId, and sort by that.  Something like this:

```
SELECT PS.ProductName, TS.TotalSold,
(if cost < 100 then 1 else 2 endif) as partition
FROM Products as PS
   CROSS APPLY 
      (SELECT 
         (SELECT COUNT(OrderId) 
          FROM Orders as OS 
          WHERE OS.ProductId=PS.ProductId) 
       as TotalSold) TS
ORDER BY partition, PS.Cost ASC, TS.TotalSold
```